# Avoiding to add username and password in each command for running MySQL from script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I know I can do some thing like this in script:

```
mysql -u root -pPassword mydb -e "select * from foo"
```

In my script I have a sequence of commands which some of them are periodically related to `MySQL` and others are independent (so I cannot use [`Here Documents`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)). It seems it is necessary to add `-u root -pPassword` part in all commands to avoid getting this error:

```
 Access denied for user 'user'@'host' (using password: NO)
```

But is annoying. Is there a way to avoid adding `-u root -pPassword` part to all commands?

Comment: Why not write a wrapper shell script or function that properly sets all the parameters for `mysql`?

Comment: @tadman Really I did not think to that, because I'm beginner in bash script.

Comment: I usually make a script called `rmysql` that connects as `root` and looks something like: `mysql -u root -pXXXXX $*` so you can get in quickly in case of emergency. Lock that script down mode 0700 to avoid others seeing the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in your home directory called `.my.cnf` and add these lines to it:

```
[client]
user = root
password = <yourpassword>
```

(Obviously where I wrote "`<yourpassword>`" you would write your actual password.)

Then you can run `mysql` commands (or some others like mysqldump or mysqladmin) without specifying user or password.

```
mysql mydb -e "select * from foo"
```

If you want to use a different file besides `$HOME/.my.cnf` you can specify it on your command-line.

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=myspecial.cnf mydb -e "select * from foo"
```

Be careful to change the permissions on that file so it can't be read by other people:

```
chmod 600 $HOME/.my.cnf
```

Read more about using option files: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [login-paths via `mysql_config_editor` command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-intro-connspec-mylogin.cnf.html):

```
$> mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=myuser --password
Enter password: <Password is prompted to be inserted in a more secure way>
```

Then login from your scripts as:

```
mysql --login-path=local --database=mydb
```

As per linked manual:

> The best way to specify server connection information is with your .mylogin.cnf file. Not only is this file encrypted, but any logging of the utility execution will not expose the connection information. Thus, no user names, passwords, ports, etc. are visible in the log. This is the preferred method for using MySQL Utilities to connect to servers.

Comment: +1 this is a good idea too, if you use MySQL 5.6 or later, and you want to store the passwords in an encrypted format. Since the OP was about to put plaintext passwords in their bash script, I figured that wasn't a priority.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a wrapper shell script or an alias like this:

`mysql` aliased to `/path/to/mysql -u root -pPassword mydb`

Here is the alias command:

```
$alias mysql="/path/to/mysql -u root -pPassword mydb"
$
```